# Need help identifying plant, please.

Tags: identification

I have a friend giving my some plants from his new yard in Calgary. Does anyone know what this plant is?
[image: unknown plant]

Answer (score 2):

That's a **[sedum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hylotelephium)**, probably a [Hylotelephium spectabile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hylotelephium_spectabile) if I interpret last year's flower stalks correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's one of the Sedums, most likely Sedum spectabile (now rechristened Hylotelephium spectabile) the commonest form of which is Sedum 'Autumn Joy' or 'Iceberg', but there are others with different coloured flowers. Likes full sun and free draining soil, flowers early to late Fall - the dead bits from last year should be clipped off as growth begins the following spring - or now, in this case! Link below shows one called 'Brilliant', and gives some cultural details.

https://davisla.wordpress.com/2011/08/21/plant-of-the-week-sedum-spectabile-brilliant/